# Discord.py | Getting info about user connected accounts

Tags: python, discord, bots, steam

I have Discord bot written on Python and I'm working on command that could show info about ur steam acc. Rn it asks for writing ID manually.

But how can I get ID of user's Steam account if user has it connected to their Discord acc? Is there any method for it?

Comment: Did you check the discord.py documentation? I myself do not know if this can be accomplished but, if it can, it will definitely be in the docs.

Comment: @JacobLee no, I didn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parameter `connected_accounts`, this will retrieve a list of dictionaries showing the accounts connected to that user.

One thing to point out is that due to Discord limitations (bots cannot access `User.Profile`), *discord.py* does not currently allow a *bot account* to use this function (it will always return `None`), so to use it you would need to be in a *user bot account*, which are against Discord [terms of service](https://discord.com/terms).